# How to set up component on another site?

Tags: 7, panels

I've been tasked with setting up a simple gallery component on a global site.

The component exists and works on a sub-site, but I want to move it to the parent site and ensure it's available globally.

I found the component's files in the sub-site and moved them to the same directory in the global, parent site.

The good news is that I can now see the component when I go to add it to a panel. But I can't access it to set it up. Clicking on it does nothing.

Does anyone know if there are any other steps I need to take to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

1. Transferred component files from one site to the other to the same directory.
2. In the components.module file (which for me was up a couple of levels from the place I dropped the component files) paste in any hooks the correspond to the component (my component was an image gallery which used Masonry, so there were some hooks there).
3. Ensure the render function is relating to the right theme. See my other issue [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229109/what-could-stop-a-component-appearing-on-the-front-end) for more info.
4. Clear caches, rebuild registry.

It's not the best response, but I hope it helps someone.